# Check if array already contains new set regardless of order

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays containing objects:

```
[ [A, B, C],
  [A, B, D],
  [B, C, D] ]
```

I want to check that a value like `[B, A, C]` can't be added since it's not unique for my purposes. The existing arrays within the array shouldn't have any duplicates (I'm already handling that).

I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
#if false, don't add to existing array
!big_array.sort.include? new_array.sort
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#sort` sorts the object but not the objects in side you could use `map(&:sort)` which will sort the arrays inside instead.

Comment: I appreciate the green mark, MM, but in future I would encourage you to hold off selecting an answer, lest you discourage other entrants (with possibly better answers), or preempt someone still working on their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'set'

a = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
     ['a', 'b', 'd'],
     ['b', 'c', 'd']]

as = a.map(&:to_set)

as.include? ['b', 'a', 'c'].to_set #=> true
as.include? ['b', 'a', 'e'].to_set #=> false
```

Use:

```
(as << row.to_set) unless as.include? row.to_set
```

then when finished:

```
as.to_a
```

In view of your comment, if you add all your rows to a:

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
     ['a', 'b', 'd'],
     ['b', 'c', 'd'],
     ['a', 'c', 'b'],
     ['c', 'a', 'b'],
     ['e', 'a', 'b'],
     ['c', 'b', 'd']]
```

then:

```
a.reverse
 .map(&:to_set)
 .uniq
 .map(&:to_a)
  #=> [["b", "c", "d"],
  #    ["e", "a", "b"],
  #    ["a", "b", "c"],
  #    ["a", "b", "d"]]
```

`reverse` is needed to keep your original arrays, but note that ordering is not preserved in the result.  If you wish to keep the ordering of the modified `a`:

```
a.each_with_object(Set.new) { |row,set| set << row.to_set }
 .map(&:to_a) 
  #=> [["a", "b", "c"],
  #    ["a", "b", "d"],
  #    ["b", "c", "d"],
  #    ["e", "a", "b"]]
```

Comment: Just adding the to_set and that unless statement works for me with no other changes. Seems to have slowed things down quite a bit though, so maybe it would be quicker to filter them after the fact rather than check the main array every time we go to push to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be sorting the arrays inside your big array. Not the big array itself

```
!big_array.map(&:sort).include? new_array.sort
```

Comment: I'm still having issues with this, I think with the way my program is setup. Initially big_array = [], then as I loop through I push the other arrays into it. With that code, it's currently accepting everything. I think I may need a flatten in there?

Comment: Are the other arrays two dimensional? If so, you will have to do a flatten on each element inside the big_array

Comment: Only the big array is two dimensional.

Comment: @MajorMajor if you want the objects to remain sorted in `big_array` then you would use `map(&:sort!)`. `#sort!` is the destructive form of `#sort` meaning it will modify the receiver directly, but if you are iterating then why not just push in the sorted result then they will already be sorted appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'd'],
    ['b', 'c', 'd']
]

class Array
  def add_only_if_combination_does_not_exist_in(double_array)
    if double_array.map(&:sort).include?(self.sort)
      puts "Won't be added since it already exists!"
    else
      puts 'Will be added'
      double_array << self
    end
  end
end

['b', 'a', 'c'].add_only_if_combination_does_not_exist_in(a)
['b', 'a', 'f'].add_only_if_combination_does_not_exist_in(a) #=> Will be added
p a #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "d"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["b", "a", "f"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order of the elements, consider using the `Set` class.

```
require 'set'

big_set = Set.new

big_set << Set.new(['a', 'b', 'c'])
# => #<Set: {#<Set: {"a", "b", "c"}>}>

big_set << Set.new(['c', 'b', 'a'])
# => #<Set: {#<Set: {"a", "b", "c"}>}>

big_set << Set.new(['d', 'a', 'b'])
# => #<Set: {#<Set: {"a", "b", "c"}>, #<Set: {"d", "a", "b"}>}>
```